# java adapter not working for condition check

Tags: java, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

i am faced a problem in the javaAdpter in MFP .
code not  execute if statement ..i did not found any cause .

```
/* Path for method: "<server address>/Trail-Proejct1/adapters/TestAD/users/{username}" */
@GET
@Path("/{username}")
public String helloUser(@PathParam("username") String name){
    if(name == "mfp"){

        return "good moring" + name;
     }
    return "good afternoon " + name;
}
```

[image]

```
[2016-08-09 10:25:41]             Adapter build and deploy finished.
[2016-08-09 10:25:59]             Starting procedure invocation on MobileFirst Server 
[2016-08-09 10:25:59]             Not deploying adapter 'TestAD' since it was not changed since last deployment 
[2016-08-09 10:25:59]             Invoking procedure: '/Trail-Proejct1/adapters/TestAD/users/{username}' of adapter 'TestAD' 
[2016-08-09 10:25:59]             Server host: Banglafires-MacBook-Pro.local 
[2016-08-09 10:25:59]             Server port: 10080 
[2016-08-09 10:25:59]             Parameters: {"QUERY":{},"BODY":"","FORM":{},"HEADER":{},"PATH":{"username":"mfp"}} 
[2016-08-09 10:25:59]             Procedure invocation finished
```

output :
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
if ("mfp".equals(name)) {
```

In Java, `==` is for checking whether two references point to the same object, not for checking whether the contents are the same.